# SQL - Using COUNT() as a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to SELECT the the rows where a certain condition is met multiple times and how many times that condition is met.

For example, for the table:

```
Animal    ID    NumKids      PostCode
Cow       1202  5            1405
Cow       3492  6            4392
Chicken   4535  1            2394
Alpaca    2432  0            3453
Cow       2432  3            6253
Chicken   2342  5            4444
```

SELECT every type of animal that has had more than 4 kids at least two times and the number of times this has happened.

Example Output:

```
Animal   Count
Cow      2
```

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
SELECT  animal
FROM Table
WHERE NumKids>4 AND COUNT((NumKids>4)>2);
```

But there are obvious errors here with the output (only outputting the animal name instead of the count) and the use of COUNT() as a condition.

Comment: use `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate (`COUNT((NumKids>4)>2)`) directly in a `WHERE` clause, that's what `HAVING` clauses are for.

Try the following query

```
select 
  Animal, COUNT(*) AS Count
from Table
where NumKids > 4
group by Animal
having COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Since OP is asking for `at least two times`, shouldn't it be `HAVING COUNT(*) >=2`?